# Can't pass TLS-SNI-01 challenge with Let's Encrypt/Certbot - how to fix?

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, https

I am running Ubuntu 14.04LTS.  I have grabbed `certbot-auto` from the EFF website since certbot isn't in 14.04.

I've tried running it as

```
certbot-auto --apache -d my.domain
```

and it consistently times out during the TLS-SNI-01 challenge with the following message:

```
Failed authorization procedure. my.domain (tls-sni-01): urn:acme:error:connection :: The server could not connect to the client to verify the domain :: Failed to connect to ww.xx.yy.zz:443 for TLS-SNI-01 challenge
```

I have verified that inbound TLS is not being blocked by running openssl's `s_server` command and successfully connecting to the `s_server` "server" from external locations.

Looking at `/var/log/apache2/error.log` I do see a suspicious warning about (I assume) the docroot that `certbot-auto` is temporarily trying to set up not being found:

```
[Tue Dec 06 00:34:02.306032 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 19521] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
[Tue Dec 06 00:34:03.001014 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 19521] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Dec 06 00:34:03.001094 2016] [core:notice] [pid 19521] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Tue Dec 06 00:34:14.596461 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 19521] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
AH00112: Warning: DocumentRoot [/var/lib/letsencrypt/tls_sni_01_page/] does not exist
[Tue Dec 06 00:34:14.661372 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 19521] AH01906: RSA server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Tue Dec 06 00:34:15.000674 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 19521] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.0.1f configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Dec 06 00:34:15.001293 2016] [core:notice] [pid 19521] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

In `/var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log` I see the following, which looks totally reasonable:

```
2016-12-06 05:34:13,247:INFO:certbot.auth_handler:Performing the following challenges:
2016-12-06 05:34:13,268:INFO:certbot.auth_handler:tls-sni-01 challenge for mydomain.com
2016-12-06 05:34:13,359:INFO:certbot_apache.configurator:Enabled Apache socache_shmcb module
2016-12-06 05:34:13,520:INFO:certbot_apache.configurator:Enabled Apache ssl module
2016-12-06 05:34:14,345:DEBUG:certbot_apache.tls_sni_01:Adding Include /etc/apache2/le_tls_sni_01_cert_challenge.conf to /files/etc/apache2/apache2.conf
2016-12-06 05:34:14,351:DEBUG:certbot_apache.tls_sni_01:writing a config file with text:
 <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName b103a17811594b35d3ade8eb763c8c42.74b423d383109b22eaecca3ea14cd1f7.acme.invalid
    UseCanonicalName on
    SSLStrictSNIVHostCheck on

    LimitRequestBody 1048576

    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    SSLCertificateFile /var/lib/letsencrypt/mRH5i2aIrWMqjsZn3jMXvdNnYV5Ejd0GBtcDoIJqQ4U.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/lib/letsencrypt/mRH5i2aIrWMqjsZn3jMXvdNnYV5Ejd0GBtcDoIJqQ4U.pem

    DocumentRoot /var/lib/letsencrypt/tls_sni_01_page/
</VirtualHost>

</IfModule>
```

If I watch `/var/lib/letsencrypt` while `certbot-auto` runs I don't ever see a `tls_sni_01_page` being created.  Here's the sequence I see -- a temp directory and some temp certs being made and then deleted when the challenge fails, but never `tls_sni_01_page`

```
/var/lib/letsencrypt$ ls
backups
/var/lib/letsencrypt$ ls
backups
/var/lib/letsencrypt$ ls
backups
/var/lib/letsencrypt$ ls
backups  temp_checkpoint
/var/lib/letsencrypt$ ls
backups  temp_checkpoint
/var/lib/letsencrypt$ ls
backups  e1pvy9TgUvOmBxC4dlkwG5Ly2mTY0DU63qhUFpBik2Y.crt  e1pvy9TgUvOmBxC4dlkwG5Ly2mTY0DU63qhUFpBik2Y.pem  temp_checkpoint
```

I've also changed `/etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf` to set the logging level to `DEBUG` and to have that temporary virtual host log to its own error and access logs.  I see output but no problems in the error log, but don't see anything at all in the access log.

I've tried running `tcpdump -n port 443` and I **do** see some sort of connection attempt from the remote machine:

```
09:14:44.388328 IP 66.133.109.36.48890 > w.x.y.z.443: Flags [S], seq 1627589669, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2834688174 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
09:14:44.388435 IP w.x.y.z.443 > 66.133.109.36.48890: Flags [S.], seq 773250860, ack 1627589670, win 28960, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 424229197 ecr 2834688174,nop,wscale 7], length 0
09:14:44.451190 IP 66.133.109.36.48890 > w.x.y.z.443: Flags [.], ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 2834688237 ecr 424229197], length 0
09:14:44.451546 IP 66.133.109.36.48890 > w.x.y.z.443: Flags [P.], seq 1:220, ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 2834688237 ecr 424229197], length 219
09:14:44.451619 IP w.x.y.z.443 > 66.133.109.36.48890: Flags [.], ack 220, win 235, options [nop,nop,TS val 424229216 ecr 2834688237], length 0
09:14:44.454461 IP w.x.y.z.443 > 66.133.109.36.48890: Flags [P.], seq 1:393, ack 220, win 235, options [nop,nop,TS val 424229217 ecr 2834688237], length 392
09:14:44.454626 IP w.x.y.z.443 > 66.133.109.36.48890: Flags [F.], seq 393, ack 220, win 235, options [nop,nop,TS val 424229217 ecr 2834688237], length 0
09:14:44.517433 IP 66.133.109.36.48890 > w.x.y.z.443: Flags [.], ack 393, win 237, options [nop,nop,TS val 2834688303 ecr 424229217], length 0
09:14:44.517481 IP 66.133.109.36.48890 > w.x.y.z.443: Flags [P.], seq 220:227, ack 394, win 237, options [nop,nop,TS val 2834688303 ecr 424229217], length 7
09:14:44.517514 IP 66.133.109.36.48890 > w.x.y.z.443: Flags [F.], seq 227, ack 394, win 237, options [nop,nop,TS val 2834688303 ecr 424229217], length 0
09:14:44.517544 IP w.x.y.z.443 > 66.133.109.36.48890: Flags [.], ack 228, win 235, options [nop,nop,TS val 424229235 ecr 2834688303], length 0
```

Any idea what the heck is going on?  Anyone ever get this working with Ubuntu 14.04LTS and apache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fought this for several hours, complete with the same output in my logs. I only stumbled across my answer. I had pasted some code from another webconfig and it already had a `<virtual host _._._._:443>` section in it. I altered it but left it in. After deleting that 443 section, the `sudo certbot-auto --apache -d example.com` ran without error and I had a working site.

I am drawing conclusions only from my experience: make sure you only have virtual hosts for port 80. Nowhere in the documentation that I read mentioned this issue, but it seems that certbot cannot alter a 443 virtual host section, it can only add one.

**EDIT -- Dec 2017** I can now run certbot on sites-available.conf with `<virtual host *:443>` in them. All my custom modifications were kept intact, my only gripe is that the certificate path lines were not indented. <sigh>Oh, well!</sigh>

Comment: That did the trick!  Thanks!  Mine was slightly different.  I had `<VirtualHost *>`.  When I changed it to `<VirtualHost *:80>` then it worked.

Comment: BTW - how did you figure out that having the `:443` was causing the problem?  Or did you just take it out in (quasi-)desperation and it just worked?

Comment: The LE project has officially reproduced this and added a bug for it:
https://github.com/certbot/certbot/issues/3981

Comment: Desperation: I was trying everything.

Comment: God bless you, I was fighting this for hours.

Answer (score 1):

You could try standalone challenge validation. This bypasses apache and should potentially solve you problem with `certbot` not creating the right files in WWW root.

1. stop apache
2. run `certbot-auto --standalone-supported-challenges tls-sni-01 -d my.domain`
3. install the certificate you got in the right place (probably `/etc/apache2/ssl`)
4. start apache and test

Comment: This is how I've always done it - why trust a script to make the right changes to the right file(s)?  Stand alone puts the cert files in `/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/`